# Implementing reports in ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: reporting, asp.net

I would like to include some kind of reports in my project, 
where users will be able to download it in Word, PDF or whatever.

Before I used Crystal Reports, but they are not so easy to use. I remember I had problems when it came to publishing an web app, so I would like to avoid Crystal Reports.

Answer (score 1):

[Syncfusion Essential Reports](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/aspnetmvc/ReportViewer) can be used to display Reports in ASP.NET MVC applications : [Sample](http://mvc.syncfusion.com/demos/web/reportviewer/productlinesales).

[image: Report With Filters]

Reports can be exported to Word, Excel, PDF, PowerPoint and HTML.

[image: Report exported to Excel]

Reports are serialized in [Report Definition Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Report_Definition_Language) and can be created from within Visual Studio (RDLC) or using the Report Designer provided by Syncfusion.

The report viewer can be embedded in your application and reports can be created by the end users using the [Report Designer](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/report-designer).If you are using Microsoft SQL Server, you can also use the [Report Builder](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42301) to create reports.

The entire product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense?refer=srecs40302) program if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue). The community license is the full product with no limitations.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.